# Ruby in pry: overriding Range's to string methods

Tags: ruby, tostring, pry

I cannot get pry to show instances of my class, derived from Range, in the way I have overridden to_s / inspect:

```
[1] pry(main)> class RangeInherited < Range
[1] pry(main)*   def initialize(first, last, added=nil)
[1] pry(main)*     super(first, last)
[1] pry(main)*     @added = added
[1] pry(main)*   end  
[1] pry(main)*   def to_s
[1] pry(main)*     "#<".concat(self.class.name, " ", super, " ", @added || "-", ">")
[1] pry(main)*   end  
[1] pry(main)*   alias inspect to_s
[1] pry(main)* end  
=> nil
[2] pry(main)> r = RangeInherited.new(1, 10, "x")
=> 1..10
```

Despite the fact that direct calls of to_s / inspect produce the wanted result:

```
[3] pry(main)> r.to_s
=> "#<RangeInherited 1..10 x>"
[4] pry(main)> r.inspect
=> "#<RangeInherited 1..10 x>"
[5] pry(main)>
```

Why?

---

With the help of Marcin Kołodziej's answer I came to the following solution:

```
[1] pry(main)> class RangeInherited < Range
[1] pry(main)*   def initialize(first, last, added=nil)    
[1] pry(main)*     super(first, last)        
[1] pry(main)*     @added = added        
[1] pry(main)*   end      
[1] pry(main)*   def to_s    
[1] pry(main)*     "#<".concat(self.class.name, " ", super, " ", @added || "-", ">")        
[1] pry(main)*   end      
[1] pry(main)*   alias inspect to_s    
[1] pry(main)*   def pretty_print(pp)    
[1] pry(main)*     pp.text(to_s)        
[1] pry(main)*   end       
[1] pry(main)* end  
=> :pretty_print
[2] pry(main)> 
[3] pry(main)> r = RangeInherited.new(1, 10, "x")
=> #<RangeInherited 1..10 x>
```

Comment: Sidenote: if your method results in raised exception pry will rescue this [Here](https://github.com/pry/pry/blob/master/lib/pry/color_printer.rb#L41) which will be even more confusing :) as your output would be akin to `#<RangeInherited:0x2f013a8>` without any notification of the error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without any [customization](https://github.com/pry/pry/wiki/Customization-and-configuration#the-print-object), `pry` uses `pp` (pretty print) for its output, not `inspect`.

In order to overwrite it, you have to redefine `pretty_print`, like so:

```
def pretty_print(pp)
  pp.text(
    "#<".concat(self.class.name, " ", to_s, " ", @added || "-", ">")
  )
end
```

your pry will output what you wanted:

```
[3] pry(main)> r = RangeInherited.new(1, 10, "x")
=> #<RangeInherited 1..10 x>
```

Comment: It works. Sometimes. If executed repeatedly (incl. class definition), it shows a kind of weird behaviour. Sometimes it outputs "1..10#<RangeInherited 1..10 x>", sometimes "#<RangeInherited (... .. ...) x>", sometimes even "#<RangeInherited #<RangeInherited (... .. ...) x> x>". Seemingly, some kind of recursion occurs.

Comment: Quit your pry, quit your irb, restart everything. You might still have `to_s` declared somewhere in your class.

Comment: Indeed, still having to_s declared was the pivotal hint, thx! But what if I want to have to_s *and* pretty_print; moreover, I don't like to duplicate code but to call to_s from pretty_print(pp).

Comment: Have your `to_s` return the whole string from that you initially wrote and define the `pretty_print` as `pp.text(to_s)`.

Comment: Yes, that was what I tried as first but something went wrong. Must have been a fault of mine. Because after a clean start it worked fine. Repeatedly. Thx.